# Is there a UIViewController method that gets automatically called when the app moves to the background?

Tags: ios

My `UIViewController` registers for notifications which my model component sends out when it has finished downloading content.

The downloading can occur in the background (by using `beginBackgroundTaskWithExpirationHandler:`) so obviously I don't want my GUI to attempt to redraw etc. if the download completes in the background.

So I guess I have two choices - 1) the model knows when its in the background/foreground and doesn't fire the notifications. 2) the `UIViewController` deregisters for notifications when its in the background.

Option 2) is preferable.

Is there a method on `UIViewController` that is always called when the app goes into the background? Or will the `UIViewController` have to register to receive a notification event when the app moves into the background?

(Seems like `viewWillDisappear`, `viewWillUnload` etc. don't get called when the app moves to the background?)

Answer (score 23, accepted):

make your view controller register for `UIApplicationDidEnterBackgroundNotification` in `view did load`...  the selector method associated will be called before entering background..

Comment: +1  However, you may find that updating the UI when waking up is tricky.  When your app is backgrounded, the iOS device will capture a screenshot and present this screenshot when the app resumes.  What this means is that if you update your UI in the `- (void)applicationDidBecomeActive:(UIApplication *)application` that the user will see the previous screen and it will isntantly change to whatever you changed the UI to be....